What is the best way to structure this python code that can have multiple permutations of input? I am thinking perhaps a Class is the way to go?
I am at the beginning stages of developing this for my company (so thinking of design and structure for efficiency):
Long-Term Objective: Create or leverage a user interface like Streamlit to take users input and also output data. They can change which field they would like to change in an object, or maybe multiple fields.
This will call on our software's API to make a change.
Short-Term - or where I am now: I am trying to structure my python code as follows:
import requests
import json
from get_loan import get_loan

def update_loan(loanaccount, intrate, paymentinterest, customfield_loanaccountant, new_charge)
   loan_dict = get_loan()
   
   if intrate:
      #some method to overwrite the loan_dict(K:V) with the intrate value.

   if paymentinterest:
      #some method to overwrite the loan_dict(K:V) with the intrate value.

With this approach I'd have to write an if statement for every field (a lot of fields) and probably will add them slowly and not all at once. Also, I think I can upload one payload file to the API once the function runs through all of the IFs
I was thinking with classes I can add functions within the Class, and the Class can hold a loan dict using the get_loan function. And functions within the class can act on that object.
But then would I have to upload a payload file to the API one change at a time?
I am the sole Python person here, I might try to recruit someone else learning Python. My background is Finance. Any experience or insight will help.
